# How do I know the age of the employee at the time of the query in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

We have a birthday column in the format DD.MM.YYYY (for example 25.04.1990) of string type. How can we find out the employee's age at the time of the query?

I do not know how to change to date type and how to find the age at the time of the request, without specifying today's date

Comment: If you want to calculate age, then you need a date - like today to base it on.

Comment: "*We have a birthday column of string type*" - that is a really, really bad idea. Never store dates as text (or varchar). Do you have a chance to fix that bug before you continue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert that string to a proper date, then you can e.g. use the `age()` function:

```
select age(to_date(birthday, 'dd.mm.yyyy'))
from the_table
```

Answer (score 0):

> how to change to date type

[`ALTER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html) your "string type" column to the appropriate type `date` first:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ALTER COLUMN birthday TYPE date USING to_date(birthday, 'DD.MM.YYYY');
```

> and how to find the age at the time of the request, without specifying today's date

Postgres uses the system time of the underlying OS. Compute an "age" with the [`age()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TABLE) function, either providing an end-timestamp explicitly with the 2-parameter form, or defaulting to the system time implicitly with the 1-parameter form:

```
SELECT age(localtimestamp, birthday) AS age_now2
     , age(birthday)                 AS age_now1
FROM   tbl;
```

The function takes `timestamp`. But `date` (or `timestamptz`) are coerced automatically.

Use [`EXTRACT()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) (or [`to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE)) to get to the age as customary `integer` (or `text`):

```
SELECT date_part('year', age(birthday))::int AS age_int
     , to_char(age(birthday), 'FMYYYY')      AS age_text
FROM   tbl;
```